# angular div scrollTop property is not setting

Tags: html, angular, scrolltop

In my angular app, I have a div which displays a table. The table dynamically increase its height depending on rows we add. As soon as the table gets updated with the new rows, I need to show the scrollbar at the end of the div.

I added a reference element to DIV and using that in component file to set the scrollTop.
But the scrollTop is not setting set.

```
<div #scrollDiv >
<table>
</table>
</div>

@ViewChild('scrollDiv') private myScrollDiv: ElementRef;

testUpdateTable() {
    this.myScrollDiv.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.myScrollDiv.nativeElement.height;
}

<button type="button" id="btn" class="btn-primary" (click)="testUpdateTable()" >Update List</button>
```

If I set that property on DIV directly, it does work, but one point I need to clear the table, when cleared I get uncheckedexpression error.

This works:

```
<div #scrollDiv [scrollTop]="scrollDiv.scrollHeight">
<table>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us where and when `testUpdateTable` is called.

Comment: Its just on click of a button

Comment: It may work if you use the same code as in your template (using `scrollHeight`): `this.myScrollDiv.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.myScrollDiv.nativeElement.scrollHeight;`.

Comment: there was a type, I actually used   this.myScrollDiv.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.myScrollDiv.nativeElement.scrollHeight; It didn't work